# Refering to subclass from abstract class

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class

i have a problem with my abstract class not knowing, which subclass calls its constructor.

```
abstract class A {

    Field field;

    public A() {
        this.field = Manager.add(Here i would like to add the type of subclass);
    }
}
```

I could carry the class-type as a parameter in a chain of constructors, but i was wondering if there is a different way.
Maybe I could use the StackTrace to find out about the subclasses and get their type, but i don't think it should be used this way.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers :)

Comment: Usually, the abstract class should not need to know about this. Type specific logic should happen in the subclass. Note that you can define an abstract method in the abstract class, call it from the constructor but implement it in the subclasses. So you can somehow influence the behaviour of the superclass constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417879/getting-the-name-of-a-sub-class-from-within-a-super-class

Comment: @JFMeier, calling an abstract method from the constructor is discouraged  since the method could access uninitialized properties.

Comment: @Codebender I know this is risky (I ran into the problem you mentioned once myself), but there might be situations in which it is useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.getClass()` wil give you class that was instantiated.

Comment: Is it possible to call `this.getClass()` before calling the constructor of the super class?

Comment: No, because a subclass is instantiated after its base/super class.

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker you can't do *anything* before calling the constructor of the super class. The `super(...)` call has to come first in a constructor.

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker yes. There is a trick to do this. But you better to ask separate question about it.

Comment: @talex how do you think you can do this? I'm pretty sure you can't. (If you're thinking of using an field initializer, this is executed after the call to the super ctor).

Comment: @AndyTurner I show you magic :) `super(myMethodThatwillBeInvokedBeforeSuperConstructor())`. This method have constraints and you should not do this for many reason, but it works.

Comment: `myMethodThatwillBeInvokedBeforeSuperConstructor()` has to be static, though, so you can't call `this.getClass()` in there. You'd get a "cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called" error (at least in Java 8).