# Is it possible to acces this.getClass() before calling super()

Tags: java, constructor

I want to call `this.getClass()` before calling the constructor with `super(...)`.

```
abstract class A extends SuperClass {
    public A() {
        super(Manager.someOtherMethod(this.getClass()))
        // Does not work: "Cannot reference 'Object.getClass()' before
        // supertype constructor has been called".
    }
}
```

I read about a workaround using static methods, but `this.getClass()` cannot be called from a static context.

> This question depends on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291631/refering-to-subclass-from-abstract-class).

Thanks in advance for you answers :)

Comment: In a constructor, on the first line, you must have either a call to a version of `this()` or `super()`

Comment: A static context can call `A.class` though.

Comment: Why do you need to pass this in?  `this.getClass()` will be the same even if called directly from the superclass.

Comment: `someOtherMethod(A.class)` why not ?

Comment: since the class ist abstract `this.getClass()` will be a reference to the instantiation class. :)

Comment: I spy an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Everything about this problem suggests you have other issues going on. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: the 'someOtherMethod()' call is a static Method. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Phylogenesis you are right. [My original Quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291631/refering-to-subclass-from-abstract-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to refactor your code.

I assume that you have classes `A1`, `A2` and `A3` now.

You should introduce factory like this:

```
class AFactory {
    public static A1 newA1() {return new A1(A1.class);}
    public static A2 newA2() {return new A2(A2.class);}
    public static A3 newA3() {return new A3(A3.class);}
}
```

Add parameter to classes `A1`, `A2` and `A3` constructors.

Add parameter to `A` constructor.

Comment: Since this solved the problem I marked it as the correct answer. Though i still would like to know wheter there is another, easier solution.

Comment: It's really not clear why this would be necessary - there's definitely no reason why you'd need to pass a class object into the constructor of that class.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It isn't necessary. You can just have consructors like `A1(){super(A1.class);}`. But my aproach will be simplier in case of big class hierarchy because in other case you will need to have two constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I am dubious about the need for this, you can do it by inserting the call to `Manager.someOtherMethod` into the constructor of the superclass:

```
class SuperClass {
  SuperClass() {
    Object result = Manager.someOtherMethod(this.getClass());
  }
}

class A extends SuperClass {}

class Manager {
  static Object someOtherMethod(Class<?> clazz) {
    System.out.println(clazz);
    return new Object();
  }
}
```

would print out

```
class A
```

(if you create an instance of `A`)

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/AkokDw)

---

If `SuperClass` has multiple constructors, you can assign the result to a field in the superclass:

```
class SuperClass {
  private final Object result = Manager.someOtherMethod(this.getClass());

  SuperClass() { ... }

  SuperClass(String someParameter) { ... }
}
```

then `result` will be available in both constructors.

Comment: The thing is, that my superclass needs the return value of the `Manager.someMethod()` in its constructor.

Comment: Well, the superclass is the one calling `Manager.someMethod(this.getClass())`; so just do something with the return value (assign to a field, assign to a local variable...).

Comment: I do not need to return anything from a constructor. I need the return value of a static method, which needs a reference to the initialization class (`this.getClass()`), to be used for the constructor of the superclass. I cannot call `Manager.someMethod()` in the superclass, but it needs the methods return value.

Answer (score 0):

...what's the question? Do I understood correctly, do you want the class to be subclassed, and THAT class should be given to the super, but you don't want to call super in all the subclasses?

Indeed it can't be done this way as the class object is not constructed yet, and therefore it does not exist. So you cannot call a method on the object yet, or ask for the name, or whatsoever.

I think you're stuck with either a class passing on to super, or add a pretty useless `public static class<? extends SuperClass> getThisClass() { ... }` or am I missing something nice? if I do, pls comment, as I actually like to know myself too.

Just for curiousity I tried different ways which are stated here: [Getting the class name from a static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936684/getting-the-class-name-from-a-static-method-in-java) but the closest I got was getting that `class test.staticgetclass.A` in the middle class, but never its subclass name which I think you want to get.

Comment: This question was created when i had my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291631/refering-to-subclass-from-abstract-class) answered. I think it should help clarify my intention.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class literal as a constructor parameter

```
abstract class A extends SuperClass {
    protected A(Class<? extends A> clazz) {
        super(Manager.someOtherMethod(clazz));
    }
```

Then in impl:

```
class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super(B.class);
    }
```